# How can I use a scml animation from spriter in XNA

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I have a program to make 2d animation and when I save my animation the format is scml and I can't open that animation in XNA.

Do I have to put it in another format?

The software is Spriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, XNA dosen't include content loaders for anything more than your default file types such as PNG, JPEG, TxT, etc.

I saw an exacmple of a scml file from spriter, and you will need to create your own content loader for it, but that is probably going to be a bit hard.

Your best bet is to take an [animation example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203866%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx), and take the pictures that Spriter has made, and arrange them into a spritesheet.

I'm afraid this isnt as simple as you thought, but manually making a spritesheet will probably be your best bet.

***Important Edit:***

Your in luck, someone already made a content loader for Spriter in XNA!
https://github.com/schmelze/SpriterXNA and I belive a newer version https://bitbucket.org/dylanwolf/xspriter

Comment: awwww thanks you again xDDDDDD you are awsomeeeee xDDDDD!!! Dowload it and im having error again but im going to try hard to fix them thx man xD.